# Why the Lerp never ending at 0?

Tags: unity, c#

0.001266956

```
private void Slow()
    {
        if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

startValue value is 1 and endValue value is 0
lerpDuration value is 3
timeElapsed value is 0 and valueToLerp value is also 0

In the end, the value of valueToLerp is 0.0002498031

I could add a reset line in the end of the Slow method :

```
private void Slow()
        {
            if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            }

            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            valueToLerp = 0;
        }
```

This will work but only when I call the method Slow once if I tried to call the method again it will not work it will never get to 0 again.

and if I'm not using these two lines in the end then it will not get to 0 even the first time.

I want that I will be able to call Slow many time and it will slowly get to 0 each time I'm calling the method.

Comment: Is your question "Why is that if I ensure a < b than a never equals to b?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexei Levenkov accurately summarizes your problem:

> if I ensure a < b...

We only enter the `if` block if `timeElapsed` is less than `lerpDuration`:

```
if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
```

That means that `timeElapsed / lerpDuration` is less than 1.

And so,

```
valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, someValueLessThanOne);
```

...will set `valueToLerp` to something that is not quite `endValue`.

You can avoid this problem by moving your time increment to before the `Lerp`, not after. That way, if `timeElapsed` is initially just a frame or less away from `lerpDuration`, `timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;` will put it over the top just before the `Lerp` acts (and it automatically clamps the value for you, so that it will not exceed 1).

Comment: When moving the increment before the Lerp it's working fine for the first time I'm calling Slow but then when calling Slow again I see that the value of timeElapsed is 3.002375 so the slow down is not working on the next time's when calling the Slow method. lerpDuration value is still 3 as it should be but the timeElapsed value is bigger than the lerpDuration value.

Comment: Did you mean to reset timeElapsed to zero the next time you want to animate this transition?

Comment: Yes, you right to reset the timeElapsed to zero. I will try it.